# workaround for dojo dialog launching from iframe?

Tags: grails, dialog, dojo

I was going around searching for a way to launch a dojo dialog to the parent window if it was launched from an iframe when I came across [this ticket](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10210). Bummer.

Now, I would like to know if there's a workaround or if anyone can suggest a workaround for this? I'm currently using Grails and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to "redirect" the launch to the parent window?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only information that can be shared between a page and an iframe from that page (if the two are in a different domain at least) is the name of the iframe.

So you could get your iframe to set it's name, and have your main page poll the iframe and open the dialog when the names changes to some pre-defined message.

Ugly, but it's how dojo.io.windowName works and is one of the common hacks used for cross domain communication.